# What is the best book for beginning wine makers?

Tags: wine, books

What is the best book for beginning wine makers?

** Please post 1 book per post, then the resulting votes will show what most people consider to be the best book.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend *Making Table Wine at Home*, published by the 
University of California, Division of Agriculture and Natural Resources. 
It covers all basics, with a good mix of scientific background and focus on practical issues, making it a good place to start for the ambitious beginner.

There is a [pdf version](http://wineserver.ucdavis.edu/content.php?category=Winemaking) available online.

Comment: This link is currently broken. I suspect [this is the new link](http://wineserver.ucdavis.edu/education/homewinemaking.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well we don't seem to have a lot of wine makers yet reading. Or maybe wine makers can't read....interesting.

Anyway, this book is one that several of my wine making friends recommend.

[Home Winemaking: Step by Step](http://morewinemaking.com/view_product/15844/102635/Home_Winemaking_Step_By_Step)

Answer (score 1):

The first book I read on winemaking was [The Way to Make Wine](http://amzn.to/b1LF9M) which was pretty informative and easy to read that goes through the entire process. The author writes specifically about making grape wines but the process generally applies to fruit/country wines as well. It must have been decent since before reading it I had never made wine and now completely I'm addicted.

Answer (score 0):

My first wine making book was: [First Steps in Winemaking by C. J. J. Berry](http://www.amazon.co.uk/First-Steps-Winemaking-C-Berry/dp/1854861395/)
I would recommend it to anyone starting out, it is simple and as a bonus you can get it off Amazon for 1p.

It was the first book I got on any form of brewing and I still enjoy flicking through it.